# Angular 5: Access element inner html from the component for dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, viewchild

I have an angular component in my component I need to access the inner html of element. For this I am able to get this for single element using ViewChild with template ref. but in the ngFor when I generate element and template ref dynamically it did not work.
here is the error showed in console : -

```
Cannot read property 'native Element' of undefined
```

Here is the code for single element:-

```
@ViewChild('emailBodyContainer') emailBodyContainer: ElementRef;
<div [innerHtml]="emailTemplate.mailBody" #emailBodyContainer>
```

For dynamic elements: -

```
<div *ngFor="let i of reminderTemplates" class="container tab-pane text-center py-4 [innerHtml]="i.mailBody" #{{i.type}}></div>
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/access-repeat-element)

```
<div *ngFor="let i of arr;let j = index" id=item{{j}}>
    {{i}}
</div>
```

TS:

```
  import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  arr: Array<any> = [1, 2, 3, 4]

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let data1 = document.getElementById('item0')
    let data2 = document.getElementById('item1')
    let data3 = document.getElementById('item2')
    let data4 = document.getElementById('item3')
    console.log(data1)
    console.log(data2)
    console.log(data3)
    console.log(data4)
  }
}
```

For Mat-Tab:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-mat-tab)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("main") main: ElementRef;

  name = 'Angular';
  Tabs: Array<any> = [{ name: 'Tab1' }, { name: 'Tab2' }, { name: 'Tab3' }]

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let el = document.getElementById("main");


    console.log(el);

    let elh = el.children.item(0).children.item(1).children.item(0).children.item(0).children;

    elh.item(0).setAttribute("style", "color:red;")

    elh.item(1).setAttribute("style", "color:green;")

    elh.item(2).setAttribute("style", "color:cyan;")
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-tab-group id = "main">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab Of Tabs;let i= index" [label]="tab.name"> Content {{i}} </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: it is already worked for single component. But I have problem in dynamically generated elements.

Comment: see demo above.

Comment: It do not works for me. for your information I used ngfor in MatTab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problem is solved. My problem is current selected tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use something like this.

<div *ngFor="let i of reminderTemplates" class="container tab-pane text-center py-4 [innerHtml]="i.mailBody" #items></div>

In component:

@ViewChildren('items') items: QueryList<ElementRef>;

console.log(this.items); // print the list of items
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works for your case but it did not work in :- 
   this.items.forEach(item =>{
      console.log(item.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    });

Comment: HI suresh, are you has the solution of above problem?

Comment: Please check you code ? is it works ? It is not works for me .